# Node.js gives exit code 4 when jasmine encounters an exception in the test file

Tags: node.js, jasmine

Consider a jasmine test file

```
throw new Error("error");

describe("simple suite", function () {

    it("simple test", function () {
        var result = "";
        expect(result).toBe("1");
    });

});
```

And this javascript file

```
var Jasmine = require('jasmine');
var jasmine = new Jasmine();


try {
    jasmine.execute("./simple_test.js");
}
catch (e) {
    process.exit(1);
}
```

on running the command `node main.js` and checking the exit code using `echo $?` I constantly get exit code 4 instead of exit code 1.

This exit code is important because I'm spawning a node process through my program and I require the exit code to be controlled through my script in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem when I ran into this piece of code in `jasmine.js` while debugging

```
var checkExit = function(jasmineRunner) {
  return function() {
    if (!jasmineRunner.completionReporter.isComplete()) {
      process.exitCode = 4;
    }
  };
};

Jasmine.prototype.execute = function(files, filterString) {
  process.on('exit', this.checkExit);
```

Since the spec file was invalid and jasmine never encountered any test suite or test method to execute, it forced the process to exit with code 4